# Javascript Mouseover event is triggered even when trying to isolate elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing an exercise and have the below html code in which I am trying to add an event listener for Element 1, Element 2, Element 3 and Element 4 to be printed when mouseover. I don't want the event to be triggered when over their submenus (eg 2.1,4.1 etc..)

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2
      <ul>
        <li>Element 2.1</li>
        <li>Element 2.2</li>
        <li>Element 2.3</li>
        <li>Element 2.4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4
      <ul>
        <li>Element 4.1</li>
        <li>Element 4.2</li>
        <li>Element 4.3</li>
        <li>Element 4.4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The event is being triggered no matter which element I hover over, including submenus. I have used below code:

```
const mainElems = document.querySelectorAll('div > ul > li:not(ul)')

function show(element, event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(element.innerText);
}

mainElems.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => show(element, event));
});
```

I suspect it is because Element 2 and 4 wrap their entire contents with the a single li...does that sound right?

Is my attempt to select the main Elements and exclude their submenus with below code correct?
`const mainElems = document.querySelectorAll('div > ul > li:not(ul)')`

Why is the event being triggered even when selecting submenus?

Comment: you could try to set an id for the parent ul element, and then you can use document.getElementById, then you can just use the parent's children to get all. But you are also right on the fact that if you wrap the child ul inside the li, it would just make the parent li have the size to contain all its children.

I recommend you wrap the contents "Element 1", "Element 2"... inside another tag (ex: span) like `<li><span>Element 1</span> <ul></ul></li>`and set the event listener to the span instead of the parent <li>

Answer (score 1):

This issue you're facing is due to the event bubbling in the DOM.

To prevent the event from being triggered when hovering over submenus, you can use the `event.target` property to check if the event originated from the main `li` elements or their submenus. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
const mainElems = document.querySelectorAll('div > ul > li:not(ul)')

function show(element, event) {
    if (event.target === element) {
        console.log(element.innerText);
    }
}

mainElems.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => show(element, event));
});
```

Comment: Just for interest: you don't _need_ to pass `element` to `show`: you can use `event.currentTarget` in this case. A parameter is more modular/composable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up listeners for all elements, you could check to see if element has children and only set listeners for elements without children:

```
  mainElems.forEach(element => {
  // only add a listener to nodes that have only 1 childNode
  if(element.childNodes.length === 1) {
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => show(element, event));
  }    
});
```

Also see example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-danny-3t2wcg?file=/src/index.mjs).